# can i choose some options in "choices"(django model)?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

id like to make a field for music genres in page and while uploading music users can select what genre music is but a music doesnt have only 1 single genre like pop and rap or metal and rock.
so is there anyway to choose more than one choice?

```
from django.db import models

class Mdata(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    released_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=0)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    genre = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audios/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()+" by "+self.artist.title()
```

also i read a model file for music page and found out writer had used 2 models :1 for audio track and another one for image file ,is it better than making all of them in 1 class ?
and how can i make a form combined with 2 models?

Comment: Did you mean like choices for the genre?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan yes but i need to make it multiple choices

Answer (score 0):

```
choices = (('others', 'Others'),('rap', 'Rap'),('pop' ,'Pop'))
music = models.TextField(choices=choices,default='others')
```

I remember doing something similarly on my app to pick dropdown values by creating a list and using the built in choices parameter.

Comment: "class Genre(models.TextChoices):
  pop = "pop"
  metal = "metal"
  rock = "rock"
 genre = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Genre.choices,default=Genre.pop)"
 , i used this code but i couldnt make  multiple choice